# Interactive photo gallery: onmouseover doesn't work

Tags: html, gallery, onmouseover

I cannot see why my onmouseover function doesn't work. It shows all the thumbnails but it doesn't make the image larger when the mouse is on top of it. It actually doesn't show the image at all, not even if clicked.
Here it is my function, followed by the div:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/sketch_jumpingman_pink_64.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <title>My website</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var photos  = [];

        photos.push({ image: "gallery1.jpg", title: "The Gallery" });
        photos.push({ image: "gallery2.jpg", title: "The Gallery" });
        photos.push({ image: "lr1.jpg", title: "The Lecture Room" });
        photos.push({ image: "lr2.jpg", title: "The Lecture Room" });

        function changeImage(name)
        {
          var photo;
          switch(name) {
            case "thegallery":
                photo = photos[0];
            break;

            case "thelectureroom":
                photo = photos[1];
            break;
          }

          var photogallery = document.getElementById("photogallery");
          var image = photogallery.getElementsByTagName("img");
          var title = photogallery.getElementsByTagName("h3");
          image[0].src = photo.image;
          title[0].innerHTML = photo.title;
        }    


</script>
  </head>
  <body>  
        <div id = "main">
         <h2> <u> Photo Gallery </u> </h2>
        <div id="thumbnails">
            <img src="gallery1.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('thegallery')" alt = "The Gallery" width="110px" height="110px" />
            <img src="gallery2.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('thegallery')" alt = "The Gallery" width="110px" height="110px" />
            <img src="lr1.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('thelectureroom')" alt = "The Lecture Room" width="110px" height="110px" />
            <img src="lr2.jpg" onmouseover="changeImage('thelectureroom')" alt = "The Lecture Room" width="110px" height="110px" />
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed whether or not the function is ever entered? It may be that it's being entered, but your function is broken.

Comment: Have you checked whether or not the function `changeImage` is being run? Put a `console.log` at the top of the function and see if it prints.